# Screen brightness maxes out automatically when watching videos or playing games

Tags: laptop, display, power-management, brightness

The screen brightness maxes out automatically each time I am wath videos or playing games on my laptop (a Packard Bell EasyNote TSX66HR).

What i have done recently:

- I bought new Samsung Evo SSD
- installed Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit on it from my recovery CDs
- Installed all necessary drivers from vendor's official website
- Installed some SW.

I have never experienced any kind of this problem before.

When I play a game or a video, the screen brightness goes to the highest possible value and blinds my eyes each time.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I found out that the POWER service causes this problem. However, when I disable the POWER service, subsequently audio stops working and also the powerplan options disappear from the settings menu.
(My laptop has NO ambient light sensors)

Any hint or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Obvious question: does it happen for all games or just some? Have you checked your video player settings?

Comment: Yes, it happens for all games, and all movies/videos. I have also checked all possible settings - integrated graphics card, nvidia control panel, advanced power plan options, backgroud processes...everything. I'm desperate.

Answer (score 5):

The Bitdefender Antivirus had caused this problem by it's Active Profiles feature. These Active profiles changed power mode to High performance and increased screen brightness to the max while playing videos or playing games.

To change the setting, go to:

Tools > Profiles > 'Configure' in Movie Profile > Uncheck "Adjust Power Plans for Movies"

… and save.